# Formatting Find output before it's used in next command

Tags: unix, curl, ftp, terminal, find

I am batch uploading files to an FTP server with find and curl using this command:

```
find /path/to/target/folder -not -path '*/\.*' -type f -exec curl -u username:password --ftp-create-dirs -T {} ftp://ftp.myserver.com/public/{} \;
```

The problem is find is outputting paths like

```
/full/path/from/root/to/file.txt
```

so on the FTP server I get the file uploaded to

```
ftp.myserver.com/public/full/path/from/root/to/file.txt
```

instead of

```
ftp.myserver.com/public/relative/path/to/file.txt
```

The goal was to have all files and folders that are in the target folder get uploaded to the public folder, but this problem is destroying the file structure. Is there a way to edit the find output to trim the path before it gets fed into curl?

Comment: Use a relative path as the first parameter to your `find` - I mean to `cd` to where your files are and then do `find . something`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you want to end up with in your path, but this should give you an idea. The trick is to exec `sh` to allow you to modify the path and run a command.

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'joe=$(basename {}); echo $joe' \;
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but your comment on my question solves my problem in a much simpler way. Thank you!